# Finding maximum value per row and normalizing to this value

Tags: r

Is there a way to normalize many rows of a data frame according to the maximum value per row, preferably in dplyr?

In`iris` I want to find the maximum per row of the columns Sepal.length, Sepal.width, Petal.length and Petal.width. I then want to divide every value by this maximum to get a range from 0 to 1. I want to be able to give a range of columns across which to find the maximum, and preferably not have to call them by name.

Output goal:

```
> iris
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
5.1          3.5         1.4          0.2            setosa

> iris.normalized
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            3.5/5.1     1.4/5.1      0.2/5.1        setosa
```

I tried using the `max` function to no avail. I'm glad for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `base R`, calculate the max value per row with `pmax` and then divide with the columns of interest for scaling

```
iris[1:4] <-  iris[1:4]/do.call(pmax, iris[1:4])
```

Comment: thanks, that does work. I can't figure out how to pipe that into a dplyr block, but that's not so important now.

Comment: @Joram You could try by `iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% do.call(pmax, .) %>% as_tibble %>% map2_df(iris[1:4], ., '/') %>% bind_cols(., iris[setdiff(names(iris), names(.))])`